# ASP webservice call to be automated

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an ASP web service call that imports some data.

This is usually invoked by a user on a Silverlight client, clicking a button.

Now they want to have that automated to periodically import.

I know I can set up a windows service to invoke the web service call, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made application like that in 2 ways :

1- windows console which will run as batch to call the web service 
2- windows service as you have mentiond in your quesion

i have noticed that webservice is more better than batch file as its more stable

Comment: I think I am going to do a windows service then, I will make it a setting which uri(s) to call periodically.

Answer (score -1):

Create DispatcherTimer in silverlight Application Put the webService Method in Tick event of DispatcherTimer Object.

Refer this Link for DispatcherTimeclass

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this means they must have the silverlight page open somewhere continously. If someone were to close it, the periodic import would stop.

Comment: Hi Weston, Actually the result of Web service has to Load to Page right.?? that Page has to open right.

Comment: The web service call makes something happen on the database (an import of data), there is no result to display.

Comment: Then you can go ahead with Windows Service. I thought it happends in One page. Cretea Service to perform WebService Call.